# Usuário Redimensionar foto em ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, qcamera

Bom dia,

Gostaria de solicitar alguma fonte de informação, tutorial ou exemplo, de como redimensionar uma foto em um ImageView, pois não encontrei nada a respeito nas minhas buscas.

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo de testes que realiza a seguinte tarefa.

Tenho um ImageView de 200dp x 120dp, o usuário clica em um botão e tira uma foto, essa foto é carregada no imageview.

Atualmente, o código está redimensionando a imagem até ela caber completamente no ImageView, porém eu preciso que ela seja carregada inteira ( cortando ) e permita que o usuário ajuste e posicione ela da forma que ele desejar, antes de realmente "cortar" a imagem fora.

A Ideia geral é a seguinte.

Usuário clica no botão de foto e tira a foto (o app carrega o aplicativo nativo do próprio aparelho).

A foto é carregada em uma View auxiliar, que demonstra para o usuário a parte que ficará visível (mais clara) e a parte que será descartada (sombreada).

O usuário posiciona a foto e confirma, então a foto é carregada no ImageView inicial.

Se alguém souber alguma fonte que eu consiga pesquisar informações para desenvolver algo nesse estilo, fico grato.

Atenciosamente,

Comment: Veja este [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/capture-and-crop-an-image-with-the-device-camera--mobile-11458)

Comment: Perfeito @ramaral, muito obrigado!

Se desejar postar como resposta, está perfeito!

Answer (score 0):

[image: SimpleCropView]

Você pode fazer isto com a biblioteca [SimpleCropView](https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView)

Comment: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/91)